# .setNickname cannot read properties

Tags: discord, discord.js

Hello all im getting the following error

`

```
memberTarget.setNickname("nickname");
             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setNickname')
```

`

for code

`

```
const memberTarget = client.users.cache.get("930654978777948160");

memberTarget.setNickname("nickname");
```

`

I have searched and there's not much information on this error, Things i have double checked is the bot permissions and it has the correct permissions to manage other users nicknames i'm currently stumped with this one

Comment: Try fetching the user

Comment: Changed to 
const memberTarget = client.users.cache.fetch("930654978777948160");
                                        ^

TypeError: client.users.cache.fetch is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UserManager#cache.get()` returns a `User`, while you need to get a `Member` (a user in a server). To do this, you can use the following:

```js
const serverID = "39883983933980"; // this is the ID of your server
// it can be message.guild.id for example


client.guilds.fetch(serverID).then((server) => {
    server.members.fetch("930654978777948160").then((memberTarget) => {
        memberTarget.setNickname("nickname");
    });
});
```

Note: this has to be added in the ready event of your code

Comment: client.guilds.cache.get(serverID).members.fetch("930654978777948160").then((memberTarget) => {
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members')

Comment: have you replaced 39883983933980 by the right server ID? if so, have you also added the GUILDS intent to your client options?

Comment: ID Is correct intents are as follows Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates] });

Comment: the only reason it's not working is that the bot is not invited on the Discord server with the ID of the serverID variable

Comment: I can confirm its the correct serverID. The server the bot is in iv right clicked the server name and pressed copy ID and pasted still same error

Comment: can you run the updated code?

Comment: Better code for you const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates] });
client.commands = new Collection();
client.commandArray = [];

const functionFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./src/functions`);
for (const folder of functionFolders) {
  const functionFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./src/functions/${folder}`).filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
  for (const file of functionFiles)
    require(`./functions/${folder}/${file}`)(client);
}

Comment: const serverID = "843909493963882536"; // this is the ID of your server
// it can be message.guild.id for example


client.guilds.cache.get(serverID).members.fetch("930654978777948160").then((memberTarget) => {
    memberTarget.setNickname("nickname");
});

Comment: Giving error client.guilds.cache.get(serverID).members.fetch("930654978777948160").then((memberTarget) => {
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members')

Comment: ah, yes, you need to put it into the ready event